# Change Image Using Selection in Radio Button List

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a project that has me a bit stomped on how to proceed in the manner I would like. On one ASP.net page, I have a form that uses a radio list for the selection options. Also, I have images to the right of the categories, which I would like to change when a particular radio value selection is made.

I have researched how to do this with a regular radio button control, but I cannot seem to get over the hump, as I'm using the ASP RadioList control, and I need guidance on why I cannot get the images to change with the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:radio[name=option]").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var image_name;
        if (value == 'AMD') {
            image_name = "AMD_CPU_1.jpg";
        } else {
            if (value == 'Intel') {
                image_name = "Intel_CPU_2.jpg";
            } else {
                image_name = "Icon_CPU.jpg";
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm using J-Query here, and my page doesn't blow up on load - yet when I select a value, the image doesn't change. As for the `[name=option]`
 part of the code, I don't have `name="option"` in the HTML code source... I have the following:

```
<tr>
    <td><input id="MainContent_CPUBuilderForm1_radCPUType_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$CPUBuilderForm1$radCPUType" value="AMD" /><label for="MainContent_CPUBuilderForm1_radCPUType_0">AMD</label></td>
</tr>
```

Where `name="ctl00$MainContent$CPUBuilderForm1$radCPUType"` instead.

I've tried to insert this as a replacement for "option", but still no dice. Can someone help to evaluate what I'm doing wrong here? A million thanks! Cheers.

Comment: Having gone through your comments on other answers I can see that you are using an asp image tag. You should include this in your question. Infoact a bit more of your markup would be useful, your radio button list and image tag etc.

Comment: Yes, hindsight is 20/20!

Comment: I just submitted an email to have the question decommissioned.  I will be posting the question again in a more informed manner, per your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the new question link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411488/changing-an-image-when-selecting-an-option-in-a-radio-button-list

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you're having is that you're not assigning the value of the image URI to the `<img>` tag. So you'll need to add something to the bottom of your function to make that assignment. Since you don't have that HTML in your question, I'll write my answer with the assumption that you have a tag in your code as such: `<img id="changingImage" src="" alt="" />`.

So just add this to your Javascript before your function closes out:

```
$('#changingImage').attr('src', '../Images/' + image_name);
```

That should get it to change the file for you, thought you may need to change the folder it's in per your configuration.

Comment: I don't have that tag in particular. I have the following:

`<td><asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icon_CPU.jpg" /></td>`

Comment: This image is that original image, which is like the place holder and will change into an image associated with the radio list selection. Thus, should my version of `$('#changingImage')` be `$('#Image6')`?

Also, as for the `asp:Image ID` portion, should I add my own `src=""` attribute, since part of your J-Query add-in contains the `.attr('src', '../Images/' + image_name)` component?

Comment: However, in the source of the page when run in the browser, I did have this tag presented in the following manner:

`<img id="MainContent_CPUBuilderForm1_Image6" src="Images/Icon_CPU.jpg" />`

Yet I find that making the changes is having no effect; the image still remains static.

Answer (score 0):

use this
**HTML**

```
<div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonTipoUser" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">

            <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Value="1">Dome</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="amd">Emp</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="intel">intel</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Desert.jpg" />


    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#RadioButtonTipoUser_1').on('change', function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#img').attr('src', 'Chrysanthemum.jpg');
            }
        });
        $('#RadioButtonTipoUser_2').on('change', function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#img').attr('src', 'Desert.jpg');
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Mayank: It is a non working solution, and you can't use same solution for all problems. I see you use this for another question. I substituted `RadioButtonTipoUser` with my own `radCPUType`, and I changed `$('#MainContent_img')` to `$('#MainContent_Image6')`. 

These are the name of my inputs. I even adjusted the HTML to reflect the addition of `Selected Value` in the tag, and still, there is no change. Where did you test this solution?

Comment: In addition, your following item of:
`<asp:Image ID="img" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Desert.jpg" />`, does not reference my `ImageUrl` properly. It needs to be like the following: `ImageUrl="~/Images/SomeImage.jpg" />` so that it can correctly point to the directory and get the image.

Comment: you have controls id problem? if so then just replace my controls with yours it will work and if you have path directory problem then jst give path to your directory. i am trying put your controls any way

Comment: @DesignerMind dont use maincontent just simply use your control id .

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of ASP.net Web Forms Name/ID Mangling.

**Update**

Having dertermined that  you are using an asp.net image tag. Note that you don't have to use an asp.net control for an image you could use a plain old HTML contol with an ID instead; this ID wouldn't get mangled. However I'll stick to the asp.net image control for now.

This requires your script to be on the page and not in a js file.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:RadioBUttonList ID="yourID" runat="server" />
<asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icon_CPU.jpg" />
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= yourID.ClientID %> input").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var image_name;
        var image_path = "/Images/"; 
        //If the images directory isn't at the website root you could use asp.nets
        //resolveURL method instead

        if (value == 'AMD') {
            image_name = "AMD_CPU_1.jpg";
        } else {
            if (value == 'Intel') {
                image_name = "Intel_CPU_2.jpg";
            } else {
                image_name = "Icon_CPU.jpg";
            }
        }

        //console.log(image_name);
         $("#<%= Image6.ClientID %>").attr('src', image_path + image_name);
    });
});
```

The `<% %>` is a server code block and should be used sparingly in aspx pages. `<%= %>` is short hand for `<% Response.Write() %>. If you view the source code of the page you will see the ASP.net client ID of the Radio Button List & image controls in the jQuery selectors.

You should also use a tool like FireBug for Firefox or Chrome developer tools to check the paths for the image once you click the check boxes if you are getting unexpected results. Also note the line `//console.log(image_name);`. Removing comments form this line will dump the value of image_name to the console, which is useful for debugging. See more info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx

**Previous Code below - Doesn't address updating the image**

A hacky solution is to surround you radio button list with a `div` or better still a `fieldset` and give it an id:

```
<div id="listContainer">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="yourID" runat="server" />
<div>
```

Now update your javascript to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#listContainer input").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var image_name;
        if (value == 'AMD') {
            image_name = "AMD_CPU_1.jpg";
        } else {
            if (value == 'Intel') {
                image_name = "Intel_CPU_2.jpg";
            } else {
                image_name = "Icon_CPU.jpg";
            }
        }           
    });
});
```