# Changing an Image When Selecting an Option in a Radio Button List

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

***NOTE: THIS IS A RE-PURPOSED QUESTION, WHICH AIMS TO MORE CLEARLY STATE THE ISSUE AND INFORMATION***.

Ok... I am working on a project for a site of mine that has a form, and uses the RadioButtonList control for item categories. On one particular category, my radio list control has 4 vaules like so:

```
<td>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radCPUType" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Value="AMD">AMD</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Intel">Intel</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="AMD Dual (Server)">AMD Dual (Server)</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Intel Dual (Server)">Intel Dual (Server)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>

<td>
<asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icon_CPU.jpg" />
</td>
```

And next to the list control, I have a default image control named `Image6`. I'm having a great deal of difficulty getting this image to change when I select a radio button list option. The code doesn't blow up, but nothing happens and the image remains unchanged on a radio option selection. I've tried various methods from similar examples, and none of them have been helpful.

I've tried JQuery for my script, and plain old JavaScript, all to no avail. I know I need to make the script reference the images I have in the Images directory of the solution, but I can't figure it out. The default image is `Icon_CPU.jpg` and for each choice, say... the 1st two, it will change to the following:

1. AMD selection = `AMD_CPU_1.jpg`
2. Intel selection = `Intel_CPU_2.jpg`

... and so on. The images will align properly if hard coded - I just can't get the code to work on selection. Can some help me with the script to actually make this work? Also, can you tell me if I need to rename my controls, or add anything in the `PageLoad` of the server-side control? Currently, I have nothing in it as below will show.

```
public partial class Controls_CPUBuilderForm : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnResetBuild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear radio button selections on the form

        radFormSelect.ClearSelection();
        radDriveType.ClearSelection();
        radDriveSpace.ClearSelection();
        radPSUSelect.ClearSelection();

        radRAMSelect.ClearSelection();
        radCPUType.ClearSelection();
        radOpticalCount.ClearSelection();
        radScreenCount.ClearSelection();

        // Reset drop down lists to original selection

        ddlDriveCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
        ddlScreenOrient.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your patience & knowledge in helping me gain better understanding for future purposes!

Comment: Are you ok with the page submitting to the server when the radiobuttonlist value changes, or did you want to do it all client side?

Comment: I would like to keep it on the server-side.

Comment: My answer to your original question will work client side, maybe with a little debugging. What you have here relies of the page being posted back, which is not very efficient.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. Yet I disagree slightly. As you'll see in my posted answer, I was able to add upon it in the CodeBehind, playing around and using a simple `if-else` structure. Thus, it accomplishes the exact purpose that I intended for it to do - it doesn't need to have any other functionality added upon it. Most important, it works on the server-side where I want it to be.

However, I would like to see what your "client-side" suggestion would be, as I am sure I could definitely put that in the tool bag as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for your suggestions.  **A BIG THANKS TO "KENT ANDERSON"** -- whom provided the framework upon which I was able to expand on to get the functionality I was looking for.

That said, the answer was to create an Event Handler w/in the control's CodeBehind like thus:

```
protected void radCPUType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // This was Kent's suggestion, and also to setup the ImageUrl as needed.

   Image6.ImageUrl = "~/Images/MyDefault.jpg";
}
```

I setup the `ImageUrl` to initially hold the default image before selecting the option on the control.  Next, I needed a way to populate the images on selection. As many suggestions had differing and maybe more complex ways of achieving this, I found that I could do this by passing the control as a parameter w/ an assigned value, through an `if-else` structure w/in the event handler:

```
protected void radCPUType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Setup the ImageUrl.

   Image6.ImageUrl = "~/Images/MyDefault.jpg";


   // Setup the if-else structure to assign images w/ the selections.

   if (radCPUType.SelectedValue == "A selected option value")
   {
      Image6.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Associated Image.jpg";
   }
   else if (radCPUType.Selectedvalue == "Another selected option value")
   {
      Image6.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Another Associated Image.jpg")
   }
   else
   {
      Image6.ImageUrl = "~/Images/The Default Image.jpg";
   }
}
```

Because the `RadioButtonList` control uses a *value-based index*, `SelectedValue` class was needed so the control could hold the option selection, as assigned in the HTML of radio list.

The control in the `if` portion equals the option chosen on the radio button list; the next statement then assigns the image associated with option selection to the `ImageUrl`, and I used `else if` of course to go through the remaining radio list options, ending with the default image in the closing `else` portion of the structure. It is a success! So again, as I'm sure there other ways to achieve a solution, this works best for me.

Thanks again for all your inputs, and another shot out to Kent Anderson, who's advice provided a foundation to build upon.

Comment: Well it does work, but I would recommend against going back to code behind for such a simple change. JS is far more responsive.

Comment: It might also be worth looking at C#s switch statement as any more `else if` statements in there would be unwieldy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

Comment: You're exactly right on the money, Jon P. Last thing I want is like 10 or more items, leading to the dreaded never ending nested block! I've actually copied the site, so I can test out some of everyone's other suggestions. And actually,  I need to rid the flicker that occurs on item selection. It only happens in IE and Chrome, and I may want to use jQuery rather than the `asp:UpdatePanel`. Open to suggestions again...

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem with C#, create an event handler for SelectedIndexChanged in your codebehind.

```
 protected void radCPUType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the ImageUrl however you like
        Image6.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Icon_CPU.jpg";
    }
```

Next, refine your radio button list to set AutoPostBack="True" and OnSelectedIndexChanged="radCPUType_SelectedIndexChanged"

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radCPUType" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="radCPUType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="AMD">AMD</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Intel">Intel</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="AMD Dual (Server)">AMD Dual (Server)</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Intel Dual (Server)">Intel Dual (Server)</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Thank you, Ken. I've figured it out. Your suggestion was rather helpful, however. Out of all of the suggestions, I was able to build further upon it within the CodeBehind of the event handler, as you will see in my answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First lets attach the JS event in codebehind

```
radCPUType.Attributes.Add("onclick", "changeImage();");
```

Then we need to create the JS function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        var img = $('#<%=radCPUType.ClientID %>');

        switch ($('#<%=radCPUType.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val())
        {
            case 'AMD':
                img.src = 'newimage.png';
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I haven't tested this but let me know if something isn't working.

Comment: Adam, can you be a little more descriptive; are we attaching the JS event in the PageLoad of the CodeBehind, or as a Private Class? You were not clear in that regard. Please advise.

Comment: I placed the JS event in the PageLoad of form, and used the image I want for the 'AMD' selection as `AMD_CPU_1.jpg` - nothing is firing. It isn't blowing up, but just not firing to change the image.

Comment: When you say it isn't firing, are you placing a breakpoint in the JS and it isn't being hit? If so when you look at the html generated (view source) do you see the onclick attribute. Next thing to just mention is that you will need to have jQuery loaded, https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: jQuery is there.  I did arrive at a solution, as I built upon another suggestion. However, I will document this one as well, and test it, and add it to the tool box. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer lifted straight from the previous question:

**aspx**

```
<td>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radCPUType" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Value="AMD">AMD</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Intel">Intel</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="AMD Dual (Server)">AMD Dual (Server)</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Intel Dual (Server)">Intel Dual (Server)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>

<td>
<asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icon_CPU.jpg" />
</td>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= yourID.ClientID %> input").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var image_name;
        var image_path = "/Images/"; 
        //If the images directory isn't at the website root you could use asp.nets
        //resolveURL method instead

        switch (value)
        {
            case "AMD":
            image_name = '"AMD_CPU_1.jpg";
            break;

            case "Intel";
            image_name = "Intel_CPU_2.jpg"
            break;

            case "AMD Dual (Server)";
            image name = "" // Insert your image here
            break;

            case "Intel Dual (Server)";
            image name = "" // Insert your image here
            break;
       }

        /*************************************
        *Old  Ineeficient code
        if (value == 'AMD') {
            image_name = "AMD_CPU_1.jpg";
        } else {
            if (value == 'Intel') {
                image_name = "Intel_CPU_2.jpg";
            } else {
                image_name = "Icon_CPU.jpg";
            }
        }
        *************************************************/

        //console.log(image_name);
         $("#<%= Image6.ClientID %>").attr('src', image_path + image_name);
    });
});
```

The `<% %>` is a server code block and should be used sparingly in aspx pages. `<%= %>` is short hand for `<% Response.Write() %>`. If you view the source HTML code of the page in a browser, you will see the ASP.net client ID of the Radio Button List & image controls in the jQuery selectors.

You should also use a tool like FireBug for Firefox or Chrome developer tools to check the paths for the image once you click the check boxes if you are getting unexpected results. Also note the line `//console.log(image_name);`. Removing comments form this line will dump the value of image_name to the console, which is useful for debugging. See more info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx

**Side Note**

I can see no need for an image control here. A plain old html image tag would work. If you use an image tag you won't get the asp.net name mangling you did in the original question and can reference it simply with `$("#Image6")`

More info on the `switch` statement if you're not familiar  with it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch